# SSIS Process Design Issue: Workaround for Variable Sharing in Concurrent Executions?

Tags: concurrency, ssis, ssms, etl

Let met start by saying that I am in the preliminary stages of a large ETL project - ~80ish data sources, with 100s of millions of rows being transformed and loaded to a (finicky) ERP system. As such, I'm open to large process design solutions, along with potential solutions to this issue of variable sharing in concurrent Sequence Container execution.

In my example, I am logging three row counting variables to an SSMS ErrorLogging table. My intention is to use these three variables to help narrow down the 'stage' of the ETL process where data loss is/could be occurring. I am currently building this out in a very small test case. Below are the three variables and an image of the SSIS test case package.

1. varRowsSource: Control Flow task that counts of rows from the source data
2. varRowsTransformation: Data Flow task that counts the number of rows after data flow transformations
3. varRowsDestination: Control Flow task that counts the number of rows that wrote to the destination table -> select count(*).

SSIS TestCase package

[image]

In the image above, you'll see the range of Sequence Containers that are being used. These containers run concurrently.

I've highlighted the Control Flow tasks that overwrite each others RowsSource and RowsDestination variables entries, as well as circled the Data Flows that add rows to the variable.

It can be seen how, with only one data source, this requires 3 variables per container. We expect 30-50 data sources per package. I'm hoping to avoid having to create hundreds of variables.

SSMS ErrorLog table

[image]

Above is a snippet of the ErrorLog table in SSMS, should that help visualize how the variables are adding to, or overwriting each other. There are 4417 rows in the source data for Sequence Container CustomerInfoAddress and 4429 rows in the source data for Sequence Container CustomerTaxInfo.

In essence, I'm looking for a workaround for the issue of variable sharing in SSIS during concurrent processes and I would like to avoid creating hundreds of variables. I've consulted as many resources as I've been able to find about this issue, (including the below) without luck. I'm hoping someone here may have some insight into a process design workaround or any other type of solution.

social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bed0d082-6c30-47a5-aaa7-0e132927bfe2/row-count-concurrency?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Sounds like you may benefit from utilising [Biml](http://www.bimlscript.com/) in your development.  As you create the design rules that output based on metadata, having large numbers of similar items is no longer a headache.

Comment: For sure, thanks, I can look into that tool to see what kind of design problems it can prevent. Seems like it offers ways to avoid some tedious work in SSIS too.

Still, I'm interested in learning about any direct fixes to this problem.

Comment: Harsh as it sounds, it looks like you solution to the current situation is to either suck it up and make loads of variables or redesign in a more appropriate format.

Comment: I feel like I can't be the only SSIS user who has wanted to capture row counts in Event Handling for concurrent processes... But yeah, I'm leaning more towards a design solution at this point. Still holding out hope for someone to offer a fix though!

Comment: For anyone seeing this: I spoke with a Data Architect about this issue. It's a known issue and the functionality does not exist in SSIS. Instead, as @iamdave suggested, we are designing a solution in the form of a package that calls the other packages and performs row counts on their data. It's the closest we could get for our Error Tracking and KPI requirements.